# This code is supposed to find a single Int in a list that is not dividable by 3 and then say False

Tags: haskell

```
test4 :: [Int] -> Bool
test4 [] = False
test4 (x:xs)
   | mod x 3 /= 0 = False
   | otherwise = True
```

I'd simply like the code to find any (not just the first) number of a list that can't be divided by three, and then say `False`.

I just started learning Haskell.

Answer (score 7):

You need to keep searching the list if you encounter a number that is divisible by 3. The `otherwise` clause needs to recursively call the function.

```
test4 :: [Int] -> Bool
test4 [] = True
test4 (x:xs)
   | mod x 3 /= 0 = False
   | otherwise = test4 xs
```

---

But I'd advise you to avoid writing low-level pattern-matching-and-recursion code when you can. Haskell's a high-level language! In plain English, you want your function to test whether all of the elements in the list are divisible by 3. That's what the `all :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool` function is for:

```
test4 = all (\x -> x `mod` 3 == 0)
```

I think this version is much clearer and easier to read, as well as being shorter.

Comment: the new test4 doesn't work, because it never says true (I could change test [] = False to True, but the empty list should stay False)

Comment: The base case *should* be `True`; if there are no numbers in the list, it is true that there is no number *not* divisible by 3. If you were trying to determine if *any* number in the list was divisible by 3, then the base case should be `False`.

Comment: imho beginners should be writing solutions from scratch using recursion and pattern matching until that stops hurting their brain (at least that was what worked for me)

Comment: I hate to see `mod` when `rem` will do as well. Yes, `rem` is mathematically unfortunate, but `mod` is only an improvement under certain circumstances. I wish Haskell had gone with "Euclidean-style" (non-negative remainder) and Knuthian division instead of machine-style and Knuthian. Oh well.